# What kind of food can I bring into South Africa on a flight from Europe?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, south-africa

I have done some research online but I found very little information and the official SARS website didn't help much. It seems like meat, fruit, animals, seeds and derivates are restricted. I plan on bringing in:

- spaghetti,
- a small [panettone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panettone),
- candies,
- chocolate.

These are all bought packaged, never opened.

Do I have to declare these items and go through the Red Channel or are these items duty-free?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing on your list is dutiable. However, all food is supposed to be declared.

[Goods you have to declare](http://www.saembassy.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Travellers-Guide.pdf)

> **Food, plants, animals and biological goods**

All plants and plant products, such as seeds, flowers, fruit, honey, margarine and vegetable oils. All animals, birds, poultry and products thereof, for example, dairy products, butter and eggs.

Pasta, panettone, and chocolate, candies may contain eggs, butter, oils (although unlikely to be an issue) and all are typical of products/gifts that travellers carry. With its *[better safe than sorry approach](https://www.brandsouthafrica.com/tourism-south-africa/travel/advice/south-africa-travellers-customs-guide#safe)*, you might want to use the Red Channel, or ask for assistance from the Customs officer on duty.